# Python: Print the common letter from user input

Tags: python, printing, count, letter

Is there a better way the write this code. While there are no errors it seems that its printing all the letters I typed sorted into a list.

I want to print the common letters in a string, even if more than one.

**Here is what I Have**

```
mystr = input("Enter a string:")
s = list(mystr) 
letter_counter = {}
for word in mystr:
    if word in letter_counter:
         letter_counter[word] += 1
    else:
         letter_counter[word] = 1

 user_letter = sorted(letter_counter, key = letter_counter.get, reverse = True)

 number_1 = user_letter[:2]
 print(number_1)
```

The only way I can print the correct letters is by setting a limit on

`number_1 = user_letter[:2]`

For example if I enter the following:

```
mystr = input("Thomas Jones")
```

in the code the printed
    output would be

```
print(number_1)       
[o], [s]
```

Which is right but if the limit was set to from `2` to `3`

`number_1 = user_letter[:3]`

It will print `[o] [s] [a]` there is only one `a` it shouldn't be there.
I want it so that any amount the of words the user inputs it will show the correct repeated letter **without** the limiter.

I'm liberality stuck I have no idea how to correct this

Comment: What should it print out? Not sure what "print the common letter from user input" exactly means.

Comment: `Thomas Jones` has 2 each of `o` and `s` @Bemmu, I think the OPs looking for repeated letters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
[letter for letter,count in Counter("Thomas Jones").items() if count > 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code produces

```
letter_counter = {'a': 1, ' ': 1, 'e': 1, 'h': 1, 'J': 1, 'm': 1, 'o': 2, 'n': 1, 's': 2, 'T': 1}
user_letter = ['o', 's', 'a', ' ', 'e', 'h', 'J', 'm', 'n', 'T']
```

which is all correct.

If you only want the repetitive letters, try

```
user_letter = [letter for letter in letter_counter if letter_counter[letter] > 1]
```

or something similar.